# How to get count of records using group by clause

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I am trying to get the daily/date wise count of `installed meters`. The query is below.

```
SELECT COUNT(ins.`id`) AS Total, DATE(ins.`sync_date`) AS 'Date Time' FROM `installations` ins
GROUP BY ins.`sync_date`
ORDER BY ins.`sync_date` DESC
```

**Output**

[image]

It's giving me a single value against the date all I want is the total count per day.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use DATE(ins.`sync_date`) in `group by clause` instead of ins.`sync_date`

```
SELECT COUNT(ins.`id`) AS Total, DATE(ins.`sync_date`) AS 'Date Time' 
FROM `installations` ins
GROUP BY DATE(ins.`sync_date`)
ORDER BY DATE(ins.`sync_date`) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `group by DATE(ins.`sync_date`)` because of you `ins.sync_date` is contained 
hour minute and second.

```
SELECT COUNT(ins.`id`) AS Total, DATE(ins.`sync_date`) AS 'Date Time' 
FROM `installations` ins
GROUP BY DATE(ins.`sync_date`)
ORDER BY ins.`sync_date` DESC
```